# Run xgboost model on single test data point

Tags: r, predict, xgboost

I am trying to role Xg boost model on single test data point.

```
a <- data.frame(satisfaction_level=0.14,
                     last_evaluation=0.92,
                     number_project=2,
                     average_montly_hours=350,
                      time_spend_company=5,
                   Work_accident=0,
                   promotion_last_5years=1,
                   sales=factor("sales",levels=levels(Bdata$sales)),

                 salary=factor("medium",levels=levels(Bdata$salary)))
#Converting it into matrix format
str(a) 
a <- as.data.frame.model.matrix(a)
```

I get below error when I predict using the model

```
xgb.preds = predict(xgb.model, a)
```

> Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) : 
>         xgb.DMatrix: does not support to construct from  list

Created the model using:

```
xgb.model <- xgboost(param =param,  data = xgb.train.data,nrounds = 1500 ,eta = 0.05,subsample = 1 )
```

and Bdata contains:

```
head(Bdata)
  satisfaction_level last_evaluation number_project average_montly_hours time_spend_company Work_accident left promotion_last_5years sales salary
1               0.38            0.53              2                  157                  3             0    1                     0 sales    low
2               0.80            0.86              5                  262                  6             0    1                     0 sales medium
3               0.11            0.88              7                  272                  4             0    1                     0 sales medium
4               0.72            0.87              5                  223                  5             0    1                     0 sales    low
5               0.37            0.52              2                  159                  3             0    1                     0 sales    low
6               0.41            0.50              2                  153                  3             0    1                     0 sales    low
>
```

Comment: Can you share your Bdata? Are you using `xgboost` library? Also, add the code how `xgb.model` is being created.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of how you got to this point.

Comment: @suchait added the edits

Comment: However i am more interested in predicting on single data point as i can predict on overall test data by simply using Predict the model on test data
 xgb.preds = predict(xgb.model, xgb.test.data)

Comment: Is xgb.train.data and Bdata same? Are you training your model on Bdata?

Comment: No Train data is ofcourse a sample of Bdata . Based on test / train approach

Answer (score 1):

You should not use as.data.frame.model.matrix. Your `a` object is still a data.frame. You need to use `a <- as.matrix(a)`.

See below for a workable example using the iris dataset.

```
library(xgboost)

x = as.matrix(iris[, 1:4])
y = as.numeric(factor(iris[, 5]))-1

model <- xgboost(data = x, label = y, nrounds = 10)

new <- data.frame(Sepal.Length = 5.1,
                  Sepal.Width = 3.5,
                  Petal.Length = 1.4,
                  Petal.Width = 0.2)

#error because it is a data.frame
preds <- predict(model, newdata = new)

# Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) : 
#   xgb.DMatrix: does not support to construct from  list

# This works because data.frame is turned into a matrix
preds <- predict(model, newdata = as.matrix(new))
```